# UIToolbar button crashes app when pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar set to appear over my keyboard whenever I open a UITextView. This is my current code.

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)],nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
self.yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
```

However, when I press the button, the app crashes. How do I make the button to where when pressed, would switch the cursor to another UITextView?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Did you implement the `- (void)done:(id)sender {}` method that you specified as the button's action?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, @rmaddy. Can you provide a solution as to how I could make the button switch the cursor to another UITextView?

Comment: That's a whole new question.

Comment: @rmaddy Alright, I'll ask it as a separate question. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Before asking a new question, do some research. You aren't the first to ask that question. No need for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and don't pass argument if you don't need

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)],nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
self.yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;

-(void)done

{

NSLog(@"hello");

}
```